visual studio code junit results not appearing in test results but they are showing in debug console
Trying to run some Java unit tests (Junit5) in Visual Studio Code (instead of Intellij which I normally use.) I've installed the Test Runner extension.
When I click on the unit test (right click on the @Test method) the test runs, but the output jumps to the "Test Results" Window and has content as shown below:

However, in the "Debug Console" the results show just fine, but any time I run a test it jumps to the "Test Results" window - and it bothers me it's not showing correctly there, as I believe that's where it should be showing up correctly (not the debug console window)?
Result in debug Console just fine:

